# Kylin sync issue with hive tables

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, kylin

I am trying to sync up a table from a list of hive table into kylin in order to build a cube. But, in the process I see metadata synced up and shows up in Kylin but not the actual data. When I try seeing the associated logs, here is what I find:

> *NoSuchObjectException(message:DEFAULT.KYLIN_INTERMEDIATE_XYZ_TABLE_NAME
>   table not found)
>           at org.apache.kylin.source.hive.HiveMRInput$HiveTableInputFormat.configureJob(HiveMRInput.java:115)
>           at org.apache.kylin.source.hive.cardinality.HiveColumnCardinalityJob.run(HiveColumnCardinalityJob.java:94)
>           at org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.common.MapReduceExecutable.doWork(MapReduceExecutable.java:129)
>           at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.AbstractExecutable.execute(AbstractExecutable.java:125)
>           at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.DefaultChainedExecutable.doWork(DefaultChainedExecutable.java:64)
>           at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.AbstractExecutable.execute(AbstractExecutable.java:125)
>           at org.apache.kylin.job.impl.threadpool.DefaultScheduler$JobRunner.run(DefaultScheduler.java:144)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.io.IOException:
>   NoSuchObjectException(message:DEFAULT.KYLIN_INTERMEDIATE_BVP_STG_VIEWS_UVERSE_PROGRAM_METADATA_VOD
>   table not found)
>           at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:97)
>           at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatInputFormat.setInput(HCatInputFormat.java:51)
>           at org.apache.kylin.source.hive.HiveMRInput$HiveTableInputFormat.configureJob(HiveMRInput.java:112)
>           ... 9 more Caused by: NoSuchObjectException(message:DEFAULT.KYLIN_INTERMEDIATE_BVP_STG_VIEWS_UVERSE_PROGRAM_METADATA_VOD
>   table not found)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_table_result$get_table_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:44359)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_table_result$get_table_resultStandardScheme.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:44327)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$get_table_result.read(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:44258)
>           at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:86)*

Please let me know what would be the issue? I could successfully sync up few other tables from hive into kylin along with the data(not only metadata) to be used for kylin OLAP cubes and models. Not sure why this happens with few tables and not with others.

Comment: additional environment details:                                                           Hortonworks version: 2.6.1.0
Kylin version: 2.2.0

Comment: The issue here of not having the data synced up along with metadata is only for tables with partitioned columns and tables created as views only.

Answer (score 0):

***DEFAULT.KYLIN_INTERMEDIATE_BVP_STG_VIEWS_UVERSE_PROGRAM_METADATA_VOD table not found***

if the hive table has database name, you should add database name before the table name, like ***database_name1.table_name1, database_name2.table_name2***